# Credit Calculator Not Working

Tags: javascript

I am creating a basic credit calculator in class and I am stuck at why my function is not being called. I added an alert to see if it was even making it into the function and it did not work... I'm sure it is something little, but after hours of staring at the screen and my professor not being able to see why it isn't working. I could use some help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Credit Score Grant or Deny</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"</script>
<script src="separate.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#creditcalc").click( function() {
        alert ("YOLO")
       var input = $("#creditscore").val();
       if (isNaN(input))
            $("#output").html ("Please enter a valid 
             number!")

            else if (parseFloat (input) > 850 || parseFloat 
            (input) < 350) 
            $("#output").html ("Please enter a valid credit 
            score between 350 and 850!")

            else if (parseFloat (input) >= 780 && parseFloat 
            (input) <= 850)
            $("#output").html ("We will grant you a loan at a 
            5% interest rate with your credit score of " + 
            (input))

            else if (parseFloat (input) >= 720 && parseFloat 
            (input) <= 779)
            $("#output").html ("We will grant you a loan at a 
            7% interest rate with your credit score of " + 
            (input))

            else if (parseFloat (input) >= 680 && parseFloat 
            (input) <= 719)
            $("#output").html ("We will grant you a loan at a 
            10% interest rate with your credit score of " + 
            (input))

            else if (parseFloat (input) >= 620 && parseFloat 
            (input) <= 679)
            $("#output").html ("We will grant you a loan at a 
            15% interest rate with your credit score of " + 
            (input))

            else if (parseFloat (input) >= 560 && parseFloat 
            (input) <= 619)
            $("#output").html ("We will grant you a loan at a 
            24% interest rate with your credit score of " + 
            (input))

            else
            $("#output").html ("You are denied. We cannot 
            loan you the money with your low credit score of 
            " + (input) + " at this time. Please work on 
            improving your score.")

   });      
});

</script>

 </head>

<body>

 <center><h2>Credit Score Determination</h2> </center>
<form>
    <center><p>Please enter your credit score and we will let 
 you know if we will grant you a loan and what rate you 
 qualify at!</p></center> 
<br/>
<center><input type="text" id="creditscore"></center>
<br/>
<center><input type="button" id="creditcalc" value="Click 
here to see if you qualify!"></center>
</form>
<br/>
<center><p id="output">I will let you know if your credit 
score qualifies you after you enter a number and click the 
 button!</p></center>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the `input`'s value to a number first using `parseInt` when using `isNaN` as the value of an `input` or `textarea` is always a `String`.

The main problem is that your Strings span multiple lines, which is a syntax error. You have to either concatenate them with `+` or keep them on one line.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center><h2>Credit Score Determination</h2> </center>
<form>
    <center><p>Please enter your credit score and we will let 
 you know if we will grant you a loan and what rate you 
 qualify at!</p></center> 
<br/>
<center><input type="text" id="creditscore"></center>
<br/>
<center><input type="button" id="creditcalc" value="Click 
here to see if you qualify!"></center>
</form>
<br/>
<center><p id="output">I will let you know if your credit 
score qualifies you after you enter a number and click the 
 button!</p></center>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#creditcalc").click( function() {
        alert ("YOLO")
       var input = $("#creditscore").val();
       if (isNaN(parseInt(input)))
            $("#output").html ("Please enter a valid              number!")

            else if (parseFloat (input) > 850 || parseFloat 
            (input) < 350) 
            $("#output").html ("Please enter a valid credit"+
            "score between 350 and 850!")

            else if (parseFloat (input) >= 780 && parseFloat 
            (input) <= 850)
            $("#output").html ("We will grant you a loan at a "+
            "5% interest rate with your credit score of " + 
            (input))

            else if (parseFloat (input) >= 720 && parseFloat 
            (input) <= 779)
            $("#output").html ("We will grant you a loan at a"+ 
           " 7% interest rate with your credit score of " + 
            (input))

            else if (parseFloat (input) >= 680 && parseFloat 
            (input) <= 719)
            $("#output").html ("We will grant you a loan at a"+ 
           " 10% interest rate with your credit score of " + 
            (input))

            else if (parseFloat (input) >= 620 && parseFloat 
            (input) <= 679)
            $("#output").html ("We will grant you a loan at a"+ 
           " 15% interest rate with your credit score of " + 
            (input))

            else if (parseFloat (input) >= 560 && parseFloat 
            (input) <= 619)
            $("#output").html ("We will grant you a loan at a "+
            "24% interest rate with your credit score of " + 
            (input))

            else
            $("#output").html ("You are denied. We cannot "+
            "loan you the money with your low credit score of "     + (input) + " at this time. Please work on "+
            "improving your score.")

   });      
});

</script>
```

Comment: Note that every comparison with a number is like `parseFloat(input) >....`. The only weird one is `isNaN`, but even that attempts to convert the string to a number.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I appreciate you taking the time to look at this!

Comment: @hev1: Better. I'd suggest "But the main problem is...", or swapping paragraphs, so that the main problem is more...main, but at least it's correct now :)

Answer (score -1):

Your strings have to end on the same line they start. (You can tack a bunch of strings together, but you can't just leave a string open like you're doing.) Get rid of the newlines in the middle of your strings, or do something like

```
        $("#output").html ("We will grant you a loan at a " + 
        "24% interest rate with your credit score of " + 
        (input))
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the time you took to look at my code!